# Recursion stackoverflow error for large numbers

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

Could someone please tell me how to fix the following code so that it works for large numbers up to 3 million? I have re-added the following code.

EDIT: Code has been fixed, please refer to

[Memoization with recursive method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951612/memoization-with-recursive-method-in-java)

Code has been removed due to privacy and a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed `int to long`, and it will work.